# Get a JSON from an ASP.NET Core view code

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.2

In an ASP.NET Core 2.2 appliation, I have a user page and I need to obtain on that page a password reset link

Bellow is my code, that does not seem to work
[image]

the `EditUser.cshtml` code

```
<script>
    var getUserLink = function () {
        var actionLink = "@Url.Action("ResetPassword", user)";
        $.getJSON(actionLink, function (data) {
            $("#resetLink").html(data["resetLink"]);
        });
    };
</script>
```

the `EditUser.chtml.cs` code

```
public class EditUserModel : PageModel
{
   /// ...

    public async Task<JsonResult> ResetPassword(ApplicationUserModel user)
    {
        var appUser = new ApplicationUser
        {
            UserName = user.Email,
            Email = user.Email,
            DisplayName = user.Name,
            OrganizationID = user.OrganizationID,
            EmailConfirmed = true
        };
        var code = await userManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(appUser);
        var callbackUrl = Url.Page("/Account/ResetPassword",
            pageHandler: null,
            values: new { code },
            protocol: Request.Scheme);
        return new JsonResult(new { resetLink = callbackUrl });
    }
}
```

I mean, when I click on the "Obtain" button from the `cshtml` page, the JSON is asked, but the code does not enter the `ResetPasword` function in the `cshtml.cs` file. Where is the problem?

Comment: Would you mind posting your code as text? If the images get deleted, your question becomes nigh on reproducable; screenreaders can hardly deal with images and even for the visually unimpared it is not really easy to read.

Comment: @Marco it's ready

Comment: This is Razor pages, right?

Comment: yes, I put some js script  in the razor page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On razor pages, you use "Handlers" to invoke requests to the razor page you are currently on.

So if you want to issue a get request you have to rename your method to follow a certain pattern:

```
public class EditUserModel : PageModel
{
    public async Task<JsonResult> OnGetResetPasswordAsync(ApplicationUserModel user)
    {
        /* ...*/
    }
}
```

And your javascript now becomes the following:

```
var getUserLink = function () {
    var actionLink = "./?handler=ResetPassword";
    $.getJSON(actionLink, function (data) {
        $("#resetLink").html(data["resetLink"]);
    });
};
```

Analog to this: If you want to issue a POST request, you need to name your handler method 
`OnPostFoo` or `OnPostFooAsync` and similar for each of the remaining HttpVerbs

If you want to issue POST requests you have to do a bit more lifting. Read up on it here: https://www.thereformedprogrammer.net/asp-net-core-razor-pages-how-to-implement-ajax-requests/

Comment: thanks a lot, very useful, but how should I pass the user then as param? can't I use `@Url.Action("ResetPassword", user)` as link?

Comment: I wouldn't pass the complete user object to a get request. I'd just go for the UserId, retrieve the user on the server and resolve it from there.

Comment: to fix, the correct link would be `var actionLink = "?handler=ResetPassword";`

Comment: I honestly don't know from the top of my head, what the correct syntax would be. Either './?handler=foo' or something along those lines. Shouldn't take too long to find out.

Comment: thank you @Marco, it worked, I have some exceptions in the code behind, but it enters the code on the server side now !